# Tycho validate-version goal fails with error "OSGi version 3.10.0.SNAPSHOT must have .qualifier qualifier for SNAPSHOT builds"

Tags: maven, tycho

I checked out latest source code from eclipse git:  `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git`

when I am executing mvn eclipse:eclipse or mvn clean verify targets it is throwing error mentioned below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.20.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) on project org.eclipse.osgi: OSGi version 3.10.0.SNAPSHOT must have .qualifier qualifier for SNAPSHOT builds -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 6):

The Maven version (see `pom.xml`) of the project you are trying to build is a snapshot version, i.e. it ends in `-SNAPSHOT`.

When this is the case, Tycho requires that the bundle version (see `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) has four segments, with the fourth segment being the string `qualifier`.

Currently, the fourth segment is `SNAPSHOT`. This needs to be fixed before the build can continue.

Comment: i added ".qualifier" to the end of project version and it works.